# How to handle deleting non-existing records in Express with vanilla Postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I'm using Node and Express and vanilla Postgres (no ORM) to create a simple CRUD API.

I have the following endpoint to delete a resource:

```js
// @desc        Delete an Envelope
// @route       DELETE /api/v1/envelopes/:id
exports.deleteEnvelope = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  try {
    const sql = "DELETE FROM envelopes WHERE id=$1";
    await db.query(sql, [id]);
    console.log("Data deleted");
    return res.status(200).send({
      message: "Envelope deleted",
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  }
};
```

I realized this query doesn't have error handling when deleting non-existing records. I'm not sure what the best way to handle this would be. Should I make another SQL query to search for the record and handle that query? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There will be no error if the record doesn't exist.
If you mean there is a requirement that your service should return an error when the record doesn't exist, then yes, I suggest you to make another query that finds the row you're about to delete. If the query returns an empty result, you return an error to the client.